# No Operator = Matches Operands - DX11

Tags: c++, directx, directxmath

I'm trying to multiply two sets of values together in DX11.

```
void Update()
{
    rot += 0.0005f;
    if (rot > 6.26f)
        rot = 0.0f;

    cube1 = XMMatrixIdentity();

    XMVECTOR rotaxis = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    Rotation = (rotaxis, rot);
    Translation = XMMatrixTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, 4.0f);

    cube1 = Translation * Rotation;
    cube2 = XMMatrixIdentity();

    Rotation = XMMatrixRotationAxis(rotaxis, -rot);
    Scale = XMMatrixScaling(1.3f, 1.3f, 1.3f);

    cube2 = Rotation * Scale;
```

But I keep getting the error;

```
[code]No operator "=" matches these operands
operand types are: DirectX::XMVECTOR = DirectX::XMMATRIX[/code]
```

From what I have read, they can't be multiplied together, but I cannot seem to find a workaround.

Code Snippets.

Forward Declarations

```
const int Width = 300;
const int Height = 300;

XMMATRIX WVP;
XMMATRIX cube1;
XMMATRIX cube2;
XMMATRIX camView;
XMMATRIX camProjection;

XMVECTOR camPosition;
XMVECTOR camTarget;
XMVECTOR camUp;

XMVECTOR Rotation;
XMVECTOR Scale;
XMVECTOR Translation;
float rot = 0.1f;
```

Setting camera/projection at the end of the InitDevice() Function.

```
camPosition = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 3.0f, -8.0f, 0.0f);
camTarget = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
camUp = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
camView = XMMatrixLookAtLH(camPosition, camTarget, camUp);
camProjection = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(0.4f*3.14f, Width / Height, 1.0f, 1000.0f);
```

Comment: Your snippet is missing a lot of types so I can't really answer your question easily.

Comment: I'm not sure what you need, but I'll add somethings in the main part of the post.

Comment: What's unclear about the error message? There's no operator overload available to a assign a `DirectX::XMMATRIX` to a `DirectX::XMVECTOR` type (which sounds quite reasonable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **first** problem I see is:

```
XMVECTOR rotaxis = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
Rotation = (rotaxis, rot); <<--- You are missing the name of a function here!
Translation = XMMatrixTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, 4.0f);
```

Since there's no function name there so you are actually using the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other). It's basically the same as:

```
Rotation = rotaxis = rot;
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here, but it's probably not that.

The **second** issue is:

```
Rotation = XMMatrixRotationAxis(rotaxis, -rot);
```

`XMMatrixRotationAxis` returns a `XMMATRIX` which you are trying to assign to a `XMVECTOR` which doesn't work.

You need to review your usage. If `Rotation` is supposed to be a quaternion (which fits in a `XMVECTOR`) then you need to use `XMQuaternion*` functions instead of `XMMatrix*`.

I'd recommend using C++-style type declaration instead of putting them all at the top. It's a lot easier to read and follow the types.

> Note if you are new to DirectXMath, you should take a look at the [SimpleMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) wrapper in the *DirectX Tool Kit* for [DX11](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) / [DX12](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12).

Comment: Ah, I realized the mistake.But I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the advice! Now I know the error, I'll try to fix it. Thanks!